# Using Keras repeat_elements in Lambda Layer giving incorrect output dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a very simple model which takes in a vector and should output a repeated element vector. Eg: I/P : [1,2,3]  rep =3 | O/P = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]. This is how my model looks like :

```
def simple_network(dim):

    x1 = Input(shape = (dim))
    repeated = Lambda(lambda x: K.repeat_elements(x, rep=12, axis=0))(x1)
    model = Model(inputs = x1, outputs = repeated)

    return model
```

However, this is what model_summary shows :

```
Model: "model_61"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)        [(None, 7)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_17 (Lambda)           (None, 7)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Dim of my input vector is 7. Shouldn't I be getting an 84 dim vector as output? where am I going wrong?

Comment: Tensorflow can't know that - you're lambda isn't executed until the model is run.

Comment: you should use K.repeat_elements(x, rep=12, axis=1) to get an output dimensionality of (None, 84)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani yes! Just discovered the mistake! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments

> You should use K.repeat_elements(x, rep=12, axis=1) to get an output
> dimensionality of (None, 84) (paraphrased from Marco Cerliani)

```
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda

def simple_network(dim):

    x1 = Input(shape = (dim))
    repeated = Lambda(lambda x: K.repeat_elements(x, rep=12, axis=1))(x1)
    model = Model(inputs = x1, outputs = repeated)

    return model

simple_network(7).summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 7)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (None, 84)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```